# Correct (and stable) vim syntax highligthing with multi-line matches

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to create a vim syntax file that has a multi-line match but this causes incorrect syntax highlighting if vim redraws the buffer when the current line comes after the multi-line match.

For instance, I'd like vim to apply the following colors using this criteria (and in this order):

- Color A: Any set of two adjacent lines if the first is composed of
  one or more '=' characters
- Color B: If the line starts with '-'
- Color C: All other lines

I have tried using the following vim syntax commands for vim:

```
syn clear
syn sync linebreaks=2
syn sync minlines=10
syn sync maxlines=1000

syn match colora '^=\+\n.*' display
syn match colorb '^-.*' display
syn match colorc '^[^=-].*' display

highlight colora ctermfg=DarkRed  cterm=bold
highlight colorb ctermfg=DarkGreen cterm=bold
highlight colorc ctermfg=DarkCyan
```

But as I mentioned and can be seen from the screenshots, when editing the file, sometimes the second line of the multi-line match switches from color A to color C. This probably can be fixed with the sync options but I'd like to avoid syncing from the beginning of the file for performance reasons.

Screenshots:

[image: Output expected]

[image: Output produced by the code above]

Comment: There's a [vim stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/), and this question is probably better suited to it. YMMV.

Comment: First, you seem to have mixed up `Color C` and `Color B` in the pictures. Second, this makes no sense, `Color A` activly matches both `syn match` commands, that cries for problems. Why match anything anyway? just set the text color!

Answer (score 1):

The `colorc` can match in the second line of a `colora` match; that ambiguity causes the problem.

There should be no need to define a highlight group for "all other text"; that's what the `Normal` highlight group is for. Trying to work against that is just asking for trouble.

This (fallback highlighting) could be a valid use case for a region of text, though. In that case, define `colorc` as a `:syntax region` (that fully encompasses all lines covered by `colora` and any other multi-line match), and add `contains=colorb,colorc`. With that, the matching is unambiguous, and you should see correct highlighting at all times, without meddling with the `:syntax sync` settings.